# Assign same value for every unique ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.9

I have a Pandas dataframe which look like this.

```
Customer ID  Customer Name   Price_Val      ID_value
5015            AXN           17.12            2
5015            AXN           2.08             4
5015            AXN           3.45             3
7315            BXN           2.22             0
7315            BXN           8.46             2
3283            CXN           88               0
3283            CXN           0.46             2
3283            CXN           6.46             4
```

Every Unique Customer should have same **ID_value**. But from the dataframe you can see we have different ID_Value for unique customer ID.

Lets's take Customer ID 5015 as example.

```
Customer ID  Customer Name   Price_Val      ID_value
5015            AXN           17.12            2
5015            AXN           2.08             4
5015            AXN           3.45             3
```

For 5015 you can see we have three different ID_value. we need same ID_value for all the three records. To determine the ID_value we need to find the **Maximum ID_value** from the three records and assign that as ID_value for all the records of 5015.

**For 5015 Customer ID Maximum ID_value will be 4 so we need to change other ID_values of 5015 to 4.**

After conversion This how it should look like for 5015 customer id.

```
Customer ID  Customer Name   Price_Val      ID_value
5015            AXN           17.12            4
5015            AXN           2.08             4
5015            AXN           3.45             4
```

**For 7315 Max ID_value is 2 so we need to assign that value to all the ID_value of 7315**

```
7315            BXN           2.22             2
7315            BXN           8.46             2
```

I need to do this for every unique customer id. I have 800 different unique customer id.What's the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: `ID_value` is now duplicated between `Customer ID` 5015 and 3283

Comment: That's not a problem  ID_values can be equal .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `transform`:

```
df['ID_value'] = df.groupby('Customer ID')['ID_value'].transform('max')
print(df)

# Output:
   Customer ID Customer Name  Price_Val  ID_value
0         5015           AXN      17.12         4
1         5015           AXN       2.08         4
2         5015           AXN       3.45         4
3         7315           BXN       2.22         2
4         7315           BXN       8.46         2
5         3283           CXN      88.00         4
6         3283           CXN       0.46         4
7         3283           CXN       6.46         4
```

Comment: @rohi. According to your comment above, I think my answer is what you expect, right?

Answer (score 0):

For this specific case you should use the [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) function from pandas, as it will preserve the original dataframe and will do it in one line of code.

```
df['ID_value'] = df.groupby('Customer ID')['ID_value'].transform('max')
```